# php if statement not sure how to do 2 if's

Tags: php

I'm trying to do a condition within an `if` statement.

I have a current if statement which determines odd and even for css styling.

Within this I want to add another if statement for the reference number. (outlined as `Ref` in the code).

I'm not sure how to go about this but I want to add something along the lines of
`if ref == 1` then `echo ref`, I've tried putting an `if` within an `if` and I just keep getting syntax errors. Can someone point me in the right direction please?

```
include "db_connect.php";

$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM updates ORDER BY id DESC limit 5");
$result2 = mysql_num_rows($result1);

$x = $result2;

while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
  if (++$x % 2) {
    echo "<blockquote class='example-right'>" . $row1['update'] . 
         "<div class='ref'>Ref: " . $row1['ref'] . 
         "</div><div class='date-right'> from " . $row1['date'] . 
         " to " . $row1['todate'] . 
         "</div> </blockquote> <p>" . $row1['username'] . 
         "</p> </td>";
    echo "</p>";
  } else {
    echo "<blockquote class='example-obtuse'>" . $row1['update'] . 
         "<div class='ref'>Ref: " . $row1['ref'] . 
         "</div><div class='date-right'> from " . $row1['date'] . 
         " to " . $row1['todate'] . 
         "</div> </blockquote> <p>" . $row1['username'] . 
         "</p> </td>"; 
  }
}
```

the bit I tried to do with 2nd if statement:

```
include "db_connect.php";

$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM updates1 ORDER BY id DESC limit 5");
$result2 = mysql_num_rows($result1);

$x = $result2;

while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
  if (++$x % 2) {
    $sch = $row1['schuedled'];
    else if ($sch == '1') {
      echo "<blockquote class='example-right'>" . $row1['update'] . 
           "<div class='ref'>Ref: " .$row1['ref'] .      
           "</div><div class='date-right'> from " . $row1['date'] . 
           " to " . $row1['todate'] . 
           "</div> </blockquote> <p>" . $row1['username'] . 
           "</p> </td>";
      else {
        echo "<blockquote class='example-right'>" . $row1['update'] .               
             "</div><div class='date-right'> from " . $row1['date'] . 
             " to " . $row1['todate'] . 
             "</div> </blockquote> <p>" . $row1['username'] . 
             "</p> </td>";
      }      
    }     
    echo "</p>";      
  } else {
    echo "<blockquote class='example-obtuse'>" . $row1['update'] . 
         "<div class='assyst-ref'>Ref: " . $row1['ref'] . 
         "</div><div class='date-right'> from " . $row1['date'] . 
         " to " . $row1['todate'] . 
         "</div> </blockquote> <p>" . $row1['username'] . 
         "</p> </td>";   
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing this? Why not just use `:nth-child(even)` in CSS?

Comment: Yes, please consider using CSS for odd/even rows.

Comment: reason im doing it this way is because its being used for older browsers ie6 (as far as im aware :nth-child(even) doesnt work in older browsers? or am i incorrect here?

Comment: Show the code with extra "if",  you have placed. So we can check what is the actual problem.

Comment: Don't code for IE 6. IE 6 is so old that if you were using something that old when IE 6 came out, you'd be on Windows 3.0. Anyone who doesn't upgrade doesn't deserve to bask in the glory of our wonderous modern life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)){

    $html = '';

    if (++$x % 2 ){
        $html .= "<blockquote class='example-right'>";
    } else {
        $html .= "<blockquote class='example-obtuse'>";
    }

    $html .= $row1['update'];

    if($row1['schuedled'] == '1'){
        $html .= "<div class='ref'>Ref: " .$row1['ref'] . "</div>";
    }

    $html .= "more html";
    $html .= "more html";
    $html .= "more html";
    $html .= "</blockquote>";

    echo $html;
}
```

Comment: thanks for this, for some reason  im getting the error unexpected } on line 15 which is    $html .= "<blockquote class='example-right'>"
    } else {

any ideas what could this could be? because i cant see any syntax error's and everything seems in place

Comment: I forgot semicolons.

$html .= "<blockquote class='example-right'>";
$html .= "<blockquote class='example-obtuse'>";

Comment: ahh im blind as a bat i should have spotted that haha, thanks, it all seems to be working perfectly thanks very much